# Search Entire Registry

Tags: windows, windows-registry

How can I search the entire registry for a string (or a key value, or whatever)? In regedit I am able to search specific 'folders' but not the entire registry. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: FYI, the 'folders' you speak of are keys.

Comment: Regedit searches from the current key to the end of the registry, so if you click on the head of the key pane (**My Computer** in XP) then any search will cover the whole registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Find window, select `Values` and `Data`.

Comment: And press F3 to search for next values (for not pressing Ctrl+F each time).